# compiler is not recognizing call to function from class as member of class

Tags: c++, file, header, implementation

Trying to figure out why im getting an error: unresolved external main reference in function

header file:

```
#define SURGERY_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Surgery {

private:
static int didhave[5];
static float costs[5], total;
static string types[5];
public:
friend void requestInput();
friend float sendTotal();
};

static float costs[5] = { 100.00, 200.00, 300.00, 400.00, 500.00 };
static string types[5] = { "Tonsil", "Foot", "Knee", "Shoulder", "Appendix"            }   ;
static int didhave[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };


#endif
```

cpp file of the surgery.h class header file that contains function definitions: 
i feel as if im at a complete lost because I have been working on this for a large amount of hours

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Surgery.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void requestInput() {

string input;

while(input[0]!='1'){

cout << "Which types of surgery did the patient have? 1) for finished.\n";
cin >> input;

if(input[0]=='T' || input[0]=='t')
didhave[0]=1;
else if(input[0]=='F' || input[0]=='f')
didhave[1]=1;
else if(input[0]=='K' || input[0]=='k')
didhave[2]=1;
else if(input[0]=='S' || input[0]=='s')
didhave[3]=1;
else if(input[0]=='A' || input[0]=='a')
didhave[4]=1;
else
cout << "Invalid Surgery Type.";
}
}

float sendTotal() {
int i;
float total;

for(i=0; i<5; i++){
if(didhave[i]==1)
total+=costs[i];
}
return total;
}
```

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Surgery.h"

int main(void){

Surgery surgeries;

surgeries::requestInput();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the function 'main' somewhere, which is the entry point for the process

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your response! I have a main declared, but when i call the function in main it says the function is not a member.

Comment: My main looks like this

Comment: I also removed friend and the "static" part of for the variables.

Comment: @K.kisner use surgeries.requestInput(), not surgerise::requestInput()

Comment: oh great that worked! thanks. Still running into problems but it has compiled.